# How to move SearchView 's search Icon to the right side?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, searchview

[image]

Here is my layout, using `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`.
I want to move the search icon to the right side,but I haven't found any method...
`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_main_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

`

after i click the icon,it will change to this layout
[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it programmatically

```
SearchView search = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    search.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work.
It trigger this Exception :
`ClassCastException: android.app.ActionBar$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams`

Comment: It's Toolbar, not ActionBar:
SearchView search = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    search.setLayoutParams(new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Gravity.RIGHT));

Answer (score 30):

you could try the layoutdirection. set it to "rtl"

android:layoutDirection="rtl" in your searchview xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                        android:id="@+id/searchView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="11.4dp"
                        app:iconifiedByDefault="true"
                        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                        app:queryHint="@string/search_hint"
                        app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                        app:searchHintIcon="@drawable/empty_drawable"
                        app:closeIcon="@drawable/close_x_icon"
                        **android:layoutDirection="rtl"**
                        app:searchIcon="@drawable/magnifying_glass"
                        />
```

dont forget to put this in your manifest application tag:

```
 android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Comment: Perfect answer am looking for. Thank You.

Comment: Great answer, it is working even without adding that application tag!

Answer (score 15):

You can add search action in menu.xml like below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search_white_24dp"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_download"
        android:title="@string/menu_action_download"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_file_download_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

[image: Normal look]
[image: Collapsed look]

Answer (score 9):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/not"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_main_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

`android:layoutDirection="rtl"` this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to use `SearchView` outside of `ActionBar` in any other view (let's say for example `ConstraintLayout`) you can use the approach posted on [this](http://luongbui.com/android-searchview-and-the-magnifying-icon/) site. Basically the icon is in an `ImageView` positioned at the start of layout (or I could say *"it is the first element added to its parent"*). With this code, you are searching for it, then remove it from the parent, and finally put it back. The result: it will be positioned at the "end" of the `SearchView` widget... problem solved...

```
//Get ImageView of icon
ImageView searchViewIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);

//Get parent of gathered icon
ViewGroup linearLayoutSearchView = (ViewGroup) searchViewIcon.getParent();
//Remove it from the left...
linearLayoutSearchView.removeView(searchViewIcon);
//then put it back (to the right by default)
linearLayoutSearchView.addView(searchViewIcon);
```

Tested, working, satisfied... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `SearchView` gravity to the right through xml or programmatically works but when the `SearchView` was expanded then it was taking a small area of the width on the right which wasn't the intended look i had in mind, i wanted it to take the full width.

Note 1 : This solution didn't allow the title to show so i added a `TextView` to hold the title.

Note 2 : When the `SearchView` was expanded, it'd overlap on the custom title so i made the `SearchView` background as the Toolbar to avoid keep hiding/showing the title with `SearchView`'s expand/collapse

Here is the `Toolbar` code:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Toolbar Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="right" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Inside the activity, i used the Close and SearchClick listeners to align the `SearchView` to the left.

```
    mSearchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view);

    mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mSearchView.getLayoutParams();
            param.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            //set layout params to cause layout update
            mSearchView.setLayoutParams(param);
            return false;
        }
    });
    mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mSearchView.getLayoutParams();
            param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            //set layout params to cause layout update
            mSearchView.setLayoutParams(param);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably too late for the answer but this worked for me, as you can see from the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USDBZ.png) attached.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:title="Contacts">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:queryHint="Search" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me. In the end, I use the approach of include a menu item with the attribute "app:actionViewClass".

Answer (score 1):

Try this...It looks as you expect.Just add this line inside of SearchView Tag.

**android:gravity="right"**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_main_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Post your full code. Because I have tested your snippets.It was worked.