# Android:SearchView focus, move icon to right side

Tags: android, searchview

In my fragment I has searchView component and here screen when it get focus:

[image]

I need to move icon glass from left side to right side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move SearchView 's search Icon to the right side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905036/how-to-move-searchview-s-search-icon-to-the-right-side)

Comment: Not duplicate. In need to move icon that show when searchview got focus.