# How to move the Search View to left side of screen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar, searchview

I want my search view to be on left side of screen but can't figure out how to move it. code is in menu_main.xml file shown below.

I've looked on StackOverflow and the solutions from the following didn't work for me:
[How to move SearchView 's search Icon to the right side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905036/how-to-move-searchview-s-search-icon-to-the-right-side)

[image]

Also, I coded in my MainActivity java file:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(menu_main, menu);

  MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
  MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
  searchView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.START));

  return true;
}
```

The above code also does nothing to move the search view to left side of ActionBar.

Comment: Read this article: https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

Comment: I read that article and followed the code and it shows nothing about moving the search view to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the icon from the menu_main.xml file

You can try this:

```
   final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    assert actionBar != null;
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_search);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I found another way already but thanks for your input and it works.

Comment: What other way did you find?