# Move SearchView Icon to the right side in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, searchview, android-constraintlayout

I have a SearchView in ConstraintLayout. I set width to match_constraints, but how to move the icon to the right side? It seems that gravity_end doesn't work for icon.

[image]

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36906959/1944896

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto i saw this answer, but i cant figure out how to implement this with ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: What is to do with ConstraintLayout ? You're dealing with the views which is inside ActionBar not ConstraintLayout .

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto it is not actionbar! it is Constraintlayout

Comment: In that case, use ConstraintLayout